# How to enable log in openconnect vpn

Tags: openconnect

I new to openconnect (https://github.com/openconnect/openconnect.git), can someone please tell that how can I redirect all the log to a file in openconnect, and how to change the log level.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me. I am adding `--timestamp` for

> Prepend a timestamp to each progress message

and `--syslog` for:

> After tunnel is brought up, use syslog for further progress messages

```bash
export vpn_server="<YOUR IP ADDRESS>"
export vpn_username="<YOUR USERNAME>"
sudo openconnect --syslog --timestamp --servercert --protocol=anyconnect -u $vpn_username $vpn_server
```

Then in another terminal tab, tail the messages

```bash
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

> This bit was taken from https://askubuntu.com/a/1062368

More info about other parameters is here https://www.infradead.org/openconnect/manual.html